# Where to ask a specific question about free-to-use software?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a specific question about free-to-use software.

By free-to-use I don't mean Open Source necessarily, nor do I mean Free Software. What I mean is: a software that allows you to use it free of charge, until certain requirements are met. Such requirements could mean: "You may use this software free of charge for 30 days, after that you have to pay for it." Or "If you are an individual, or company consisting of less than 100 employess; you may use this software free of charge."

An example of one such software is Xamarin. [Xamarin License Page](https://www.xamarin.com/license)

I guess "free-to-use" software COULD fall under the category of Open Source or Free Software, or other similar terms, but not necessarily.

I am writing an essay on the subject of tools for developing mobile applications, and I need to ask the following question: "Could somebody please direct me to one (or more) study (studies) arguing advantages and disadvantages of using free-to-use software?"

Note: I am not asking the question here, I am merely explaining my question, so that you can more accurately guide me to where I should ask my question.

So what I need is: where do I go to ask questions related to academic work on the above-mentioned subject? (I also gladly take suggestions on how to improve my question, so that people will understand my specific needs.)

Comment: "Could somebody please direct me to one (or more) study (studies)" - sounds like a recommendation question and those are off-topic on almost all sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid your question does not have a place on Stack Exchange.
Your question is part of your research for your essay:

> I am writing an essay on the subject of tools for developing mobile applications, and I need to ask the following question: "Could somebody please direct me to one (or more) study (studies) arguing advantages and disadvantages of using free-to-use software?"

At this point, you are asking for off-site resources; these are off-topic on almost all Stack Exchange sites. The few exceptions are Software Recommendations and Hardware Recommendations, and after these sites were created, it was decided not to create any more "Recommendations" sites in the foreseeable future.

If you have a question about the license for a specific tool... it could be on-topic on [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com) if it is an Open Source tool; or on [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com). I must add that Law Stack Exchange does **not** offer legal advice, only clarifications of the law. So "can I use X" would be off-topic, but "Why did the judge rule Y in Foo vs Bar" should be OK.

I've had a look at [Economics Stack Exchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com) too, but their only posts about licenses discuss how they work in an economic system. These posts are not about the merits or drawbacks for end users, which seems off-topic there too.

You have a few other options, though. If you can find a chatroom that is open to this kind of thing, you can informally ask for help there. The alternative is to find other sites beyond Stack Exchange.

Comment: If chat for [opensource.se] is active, asking there might be an option.